# lwc - How to get a list of all contacts associated with an opportunity?

Tags: lightning-web-components, opportunity, opportunitycontactrole

I am building a Lightning Web Component (lwc) which is placed on an Opportunity record page. I can easily get basic information on the opportunity with a `@wire` service, such as:

```javascript
  @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields: OPPORTUNITY_FIELDS }) opportunity

  get opportunityName() {
    return getFieldValue(this.opportunity.data, 'Opportunity.Name')
  }
```

But I also need to get a list of all of the contact records wich is associated with the opportunity. I have searched the documentation, but I can't find any way to do this from lwc. Does anyone have an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the **getRelatedListRecords** wire adapter to get RelatedList records (in your case for an opportunity).

Documentation : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_wire_adapters_get_related_list_records

Comment: Hi @prabuddh-kumar, Thanks for your answer, but this does not seem to be working for me. This is what I'm using:

```
@wire(getRelatedListRecords, {
    parentRecordId: '0067a00000O0aB8AAJ',
    relatedListId: 'OpportunityContactRoles',
    fields: ['Contact.Email'],
  })dealContacts({ error, data }) {
    console.log('res', data, error)
    if (data) {
      this.contacts = data.records
      this.error = undefined
    } else if (error) {
      this.error = error
      this.contacts = undefined
    }
  }
```

But `data` and `error` are always undefined. Any ideas why?

Comment: I found the problem: `Contact.Email` is not a valid field. When I changed this to `OpportunityContactRole.ContactId` it worked.